# Rails gem api method chaining dynamic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am a fan of [Grackle](https://github.com/hayesdavis/grackle) and [Gibbon](https://github.com/amro/gibbon) as they make api queries very simple. I like for example that with grackle, you can chain the methods which will interpolate to the url request. For example:

```
client.users.show? :screen_name=>'some_user' 
#http://twitter.com/users/show.json?screen_name=some_user
```

Notice the `.users` and `.show` results to `/users/show`

How can I write code to do so? Such that I can have

```
Some_class.method1.method2
```

Answer (score 1):

Method chaining usually works by implementing instance methods that serve two purposes:

1. change some internal state of the class
2. return the instance itself

Here's an example from [A Guide to Method Chaining](http://www.sitepoint.com/a-guide-to-method-chaining/):

```
class Person

  def name(value)
    @name = value
    self
  end

  def age(value)
    @age = value
    self
  end

end
```

That way, you can change the internal state while chaining methods:

```
> person = Person.new
# => #<Person:0x007ff202829e38>
> person.name('Baz')
# => #<Person:0x007ff202829e38 @name="Baz">
> person.name('Baz').age(21)
# => #<Person:0x007ff202829e38 @name="Baz", @age=21>
```

You can find more details in the post [Method chaining and lazy evaluation in Ruby](http://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/2011/method-chaining-and-lazy-evaluation-in-ruby/).

In your case, I'd suggest `@resource` and `@action` instance vars that are set by the methods `users` and `show`, respectively.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Tom I've updated my answer. Thanks for the feedback, I expect the answer to be way more helpful now :) Please consider taking back your downvote. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't downvote the answer. Just flagged it and posted the comment.

Comment: Hi folks. While this is a pretty good answer, It doesn't answer the question. I was asking about dynamically naming the methods that will interpolate to the correct url for API calling, not method chaining.

Comment: @MohamedElMahallawy I haven't done this kind of metaprogramming in Ruby but in Groovy you can synthesize methods at runtime by overriding the `methodMissing` method. Ruby [seems to support a similar mechanism](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_method_missing.html). Perhaps you could intercept calls to non-existent methods and use their names to build a URL.

Comment: Yep, method_missing is the way to go!