# What does def <<(path) mean in rails/ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

While looking through gem file for [Grackle](https://github.com/hayesdavis/grackle/blob/master/lib/grackle/client.rb), found this method:

```
def <<(path)
  self.path << path
end
```

What does it mean and do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a definition of `<<` method, which could also be used in "operator" manner, like this:

```
a << path
```

It's commonly used syntax sugar in Ruby. In fact, if you do

```
2 + 4
```

you're really calling `+` method on `2` object with parameter of `4`, like this:

```
2.+(4)
```

You can check on your own, that this last notation also works correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, got a question for you regarding method chaining and interpolation. Wrote about it but the answers were no good: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24796143/rails-gem-api-method-chaining-dynamic/24796200#24796200

Comment: @MohamedElMahallawy I'll give it a look. But it has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: Im trying to reverse engineer it that's why. This is a function that stood out. Trying to accept the question :D but need few minutes

Comment: @MohamedElMahallawy you will be able to do this in 2 minutes.

Comment: Done thanks for the help! If you can give me some guidance on the other question, that'd be superb!