# What does def <<(some param) mean in Ruby? How is it used in a class?

Tags: ruby, methods, struct

I know this question has been asked previously [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24810986/what-does-def-path-mean-in-rails-ruby) but the answer wasn't satisfactory. In context of the following code snippet:

```
  class MyClass

   Member = Struct.new(:name)

   def initialize
     @members = []
   end

   def <<(name)
     @members << Member.new(name)
   end
end
```

How is the method `<<` called or used? What is it doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your class definition for `MyClass`:

- `Member` is a class equal to an instance of the `Struct` class.
- `mc = MyClass.new` initializes the instance variable `@members` to an empty array.
- `mc << "Bob"` is the same as `mc.<<("Bob")` and causes the struct  `Member.new("Bob")` to be appended to the array `@members`. You are defining `MyClass#<<` by using [Array#<<](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C) within the method definition (since `@members` is an array).

`mc << "Bob"` is obtained from `mc.<<("Bob")` by dropping the optional parentheses around `<<`'s argument (`"Bob"`) and adding a teaspoon of ["syntactic sugar"](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_syntactic_sugar.html), permitting you to replace the first period with one or more spaces. It's analogous to `2 + 4`, which is in fact `2.+(4) #=> 6`. (Try it.)

Comment: That isn't exactly what I asked but something very informative. Thank you.

Comment: On second thoughts, this is the best explanation to my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it like this:

```
mc = MyClass.new
mc << 'George Clooney'
```

Comment: That answers one part of my question. Thank you.

Comment: Great. What part of the question is missing?

Comment: The part which is in the title. Somehow I couldn't understand the purpose of def <<(some param) but I'm glad it's crystal clear to me. Your answer helped too.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is a method and we use it as `operator`. So in your question

```
def <<(name)
 @members << Member.new(name)
end
```

This first line `def <<(name)`is method **overloading** of method for class which is also known as monkey patches.
Second line `@members << Member.new(name)` is  analogous to 2 + 4 as **Cary** said.

Comment: `<<` is being defined as an instance method for the class `MyClass`; it's not overriding `Array#array`.

Comment: yeah. But its kind of operator overloading . For this scenario its a monkey patch. str << 'test' would fire this method.

Comment: "Monkey patching" refers to redefining one of Ruby's built-in methods. We're just defining a method `<<` for the custom class `MyClass`. If `str` in your example is a string, `str << '` would invoke `String#<<`, not `MyClass#<<`.

Comment: Ok. Just for information. If we would even call str << within the MyClass. It  would invoke String#<< ?